# kernel interface not handled request in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, request, kernel

I have one running project on LIVE server and I have just download it and try to run in the localhost,
but it gives error

```
This page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

I have started to debug step by step from `index.php` by adding `exit()`
i have reach to **public/index.php** and inside that the **ERROR** comming from

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
)->send();
```

I have check the `$request` it was giving the response but `$kernel->handle` is not handling the request as i think.

Please guide me on this what should I approach next?

Comment: check the server logs for what the actual error is ...

Comment: @lagbox I have check that sir, the last log was some old day query error which i have solved, so nothing new in the error log.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the `storage/logs/laravel.log` file? This file may give you a better idea of the actual issue.

One more thing you can try running the `composer dumpautoload` command.

Comment: I have try all the above, all cache clear, composer update, autload all but nothing working

Comment: As its an HTTP 500 Error, you need to check in the laravel.log file or Nginx log file. These files will give you the clue what's the exact issue.